# meteor runs production mode by default on local machine

Tags: meteor

As noted on [meteor forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-running-production-mode-on-local-machine-by-default/37095?u=sello), my projects seem to run in production mode by default on my local machine without me explicitly telling it to, I tried reinstalling meteor that didn't work, it is set to production mode on every project I create, can someone assist reverting this. I need meteor to be in development mode on my local machine.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that it runs in production mode?

Comment: i do not think it runs on production mode, i know it does, because i have put checks on my code to see if it run dev or production mode. `Meteor.isProduction` returns true.

Comment: Is your `NODE_ENV` environment variable set?

Comment: @MasterAM it is set to production as i noted in the post, but what i cannot seem to figure out is why is set to production when i'm on the development environment

Comment: Because if the env variable is set, then Meteor decides on its mode based on it. What happens if you unset it or set it to `development`? On a side note, all of the *relevant* info should be in your question and not in a remote link, and I don't see you mention it in the forum post.

Comment: thanks for the efforts to assists, I managed to solve the issue.

Comment: Then you should explain how you did it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem was here but I managed to solve the problem by just restarting my PC then ran my meteor projects, voila meteor is back to development mode.